# API / dataset for Singapore cinemas showtimes

Tags: data-request, film, singapore

Are there any APIs or dataset for the list of movie showtimes in Singapore?

Official websites from [theatre operators in Singapore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_movie_theatre_operators_in_Singapore), (e.g. [Eng Wah](https://www.wecinemas.com.sg/), [Shaw](http://www.shaw.sg/), [Cathay](http://www.cathaycineplexes.com.sg/), [Filmgarde](http://fgcineplex.com.sg/), [Golden Village](http://www.gv.com.sg)) does show the data but **it's truncated**  (data is only available for showtimes right then and onwards; showtimes of previous days will no longer be showed).

Also, is there any way to obtain misc info regarding the shows? This includes the seat information (2D; DBox; IMAX; Dolby Atmos; type of 3D; HFR), the set of available / occupied seats, and the seats booking cost, discounts and booking limitations.

Comment: I am also doing something similar. did u manage to find out?