# Current movie data in area

Tags: film

I want data of all the current movies that are playing in or around a given zip code, with the locations and showing times. Is there any database with this level of detail?

How does a service like Fandango get this information? Do they have deals with all the local movie theaters who push the data to Fandango? Or do they pull the data from some other source?

Comment: What country/-ies? You are on a world wide website.

Comment: similar question = https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5545/1511